# Blazor server app .net6.0 - Intermittent issues while uploading files

Tags: .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I am facing an issue when the client uploads a file in Blazor Server app. This doesnt happen everytime, but this does happen each day for some users & its pretty adhoc. Below is the error:

**System.TimeoutException: Did not receive any data in the allotted time.**     at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)     at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()     at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeReaderStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSDataStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.CopyFileDataIntoBuffer(Int64 sourceOffset, Memory`1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

When I turned on the DEBUG mode for this, I get the below error prior to the failure.

**Socket connection closed prematurely.**

System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.     at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ThrowIfEOFUnexpected(Boolean throwOnPrematureClosure)     at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.EnsureBufferContainsAsync(Int32 minimumRequiredBytes, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean throwOnPrematureClosure)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)     at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TResult](Memory`1 payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsServerTransport.StartReceiving(WebSocket socket)

**Any ideas or help is appreciated !**

Tried increasing the JSInteropDefaultCallTimeout , but did not work

Created a custom Hub for the file upload, where we start a new connection each time the file is uploaded, but that did not  help

Increased MaximumReceiveMessageSize to 64KB , that did not help